# Very difference between lines on Highstock

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I have two diferents values:

```
{
  name: 'Propuestas',
  color: '#50B432',
  data: [<?php echo join($resultado, ',') ?>]
}
```

And

```
{
  name: 'Ingresos',
  color: '#AA1111',
  data: [<?php echo join($resultado_in, ',') ?>]
}
```

This work correctly, but the result is very different and draw a chart like this...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6nX.jpg]

The green line is very linear, is possible adjust the two lines like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

(I can't use this method because is highchart and i use highstock)

Thanks!

--------------EDIT---------------

I used this highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

And this is my code:

```
$(function() {
        // Create the chart
        $('#lineasAc').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#lineasAc').width() > 480
            },

            title : {
                text : ''
            },

             series: [{
     name: 'Propuestas',
     color: '#50B432',
     data: [<?php echo join($resultado, ',') ?>],
     marker: {
         enabled: true,
         radius: 3
     },
     shadow: true,
     tooltip: {
         valueDecimals: 0
     }
      },

      {
     name: 'Ingresos',
     color: '#AA1111',
     data: [<?php echo join($resultado_in, ',') ?>],
     marker: {
         enabled: true,
         radius: 3
     },
     shadow: true,
     tooltip: {
         valueDecimals: 0,
         valueSuffix: ' €'
     }
      }

      ]
        });

});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The graph is showing the information you're giving it, but you want to make it more linear? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: No no, the two lines are very different, i want the two lines similar, but not linear. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

But i can't use this method because is a highchart and i use highstock :/

Comment: The highstock print a line chart as you have, but in HS is more points, so I still no see your goal.

Comment: I need how two different references or a percentage. In the jsfiddle example MSFT have 26 points and AAPL have 550, but the lines are similar, my lines are very different. I need something like this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/FRsrG.jpg

There are very diference between point (300 at left and 300000 at right), but the lines are similar. The green line are not linear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to compare with percent:

```
 plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                }
            },
```